# Using for-in loop to iterate localStorage returns spurious entries

Tags: javascript, local-storage, for-in-loop

I am trying to make a basic notes app using JS.

I am storing notes in localStorage, and I am trying to print those notes using for-in loop.  It works mostly fine, but I don’t know why I am getting extra values like `length`, `getItem`, `key`, etc.  Can anyone help?

My code:

```
for (const key in localStorage) {
    let notes = document.getElementById("notes");
    let value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    notes.innerHTML = notes.innerHTML + `${key}: ${value} <br>`;
}
```

Comment: See [Why is using "for...in" for array iteration a bad idea?](/a/53915628/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` (and likewise `sessionStorage`) is an object similar to `Map`, in that its own properties and methods don’t directly correspond to values actually kept in the storage.  Enumerating its properties and accessing missing properties on it will fall back to returning items from the underlying storage, but that is actually [a design flaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592579/) that is best not relied on.

To enumerate the contents of a storage object (`localStorage` or `sessionStorage`), you shouldn’t use `for`-`in`, `Object.keys` or `Object.entries`.  Use `key`, `length` and `getItem`:

```js
function* storageEntries(storage) {
    for (let i = 0; i < storage.length; ++i) {
        const key = storage.key(i); 
        yield [key, storage.getItem(key)];
    }
}

for (const [key, val] of storageEntries(localStorage)) {
    console.info(
        `localStorage ${JSON.stringify(key)} maps to ${JSON.stringify(val)}`);
}
```

Using the `for`-`in` loop and property accesses will return properties of the `localStorage` object itself, while using `Object.entries` or `Object.keys` will skip them even if there actually *are* storage items with the same keys.  For example:

```js
localStorage.clear();
localStorage.setItem('length', -69420);
localStorage.setItem('getItem', 'where is your god now?');

// returns wrong values
const result0 = [];
for (var key in localStorage) {
    result0.push(key, localStorage[key]);
}
console.log('WRONG:', result0);

// returns right values, but also spurious keys
const result1 = [];
for (var key in localStorage) {
    result1.push(key, localStorage.getItem(key));
}
console.log('WRONG:', result1);

// returns an empty array
console.log('WRONG:', Object.entries(localStorage));

// returns two key-value pairs
console.log('RIGHT:', Array.from(storageEntries(localStorage)));
```

As an aside though, keep in mind that each storage object provides a single namespace shared by all scripts that happen to be running on your page.  If any other script you use decides to store items in `localStorage` as well, those may appear as ‘notes’ in your app, and modifying them may corrupt those other scripts’ data.  You may be better off at the very least prefixing (or suffixing) storage keys you use with something specific to your app, to section them off and minimise the risk of clashes.

Answer (score -2):

`localStorage` is an object with properties and methods. You're looping over all of these as well as the item items when you're performing the `for of` loop.

To ensure you only get the actual keys and values within `localStorage` then you can use `Object.entries()`.

For example:

```
Object.entries(localStorage).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  let notes = document.getElementById("notes");
  notes.innerHTML = notes.innerHTML + `${key}: ${value} <br>`
});
```